# Adding slf4j-log4j12 started logging to server.log

Tags: java, maven, jboss, slf4j

`amqps(RabbitMQ client)` jar requires the implementation of the slf4j-log4j12 to be included or else it is throwing the `NoSuchMethodError` in he logs. So, I added it to the `pom.xml`. Now the logging is messed up in jboss 5.1, all application logs are now logging in the console/server.log file.

We use jboss default logging for all our applications they are located at DOMAIN/log folder.

**Error when the jar is not included in the app**

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
```

POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>

        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It means more than on dependency is pulling a different version of slf4j. Class loader is loading a version that doesn't have StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton() method. To check which dependencies are pulling in different versions of slf4j use maven dependency:tree

The exact command is

**mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=/somepath/file.txt**

the latest maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How do I fix my logging of my jboss? It does look like the slf4j 1.7.x is being used by the through out after I put the dependancy in the pom.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to exclude logging default services from jboss.

To achieve that you can add a file called [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html) in your WEB-INF for JAR or WAR, on META-INF for EAR.

In which you can add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

don't forget to add the xml file to your class path (example given for EAR):

```
               <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                        <earSourceDirectory>ear</earSourceDirectory>
                        <earSourceIncludes>META-INF/*</earSourceIncludes>
                        <modules>
                            <webModule>
                                <groupId>your group id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>your artifact</artifactId>
                                <contextRoot>/yourcontext</contextRoot>
                            </webModule>
                        </modules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Then the logging should be working provided you add the right dependencies in your pom.xml and use the right logger in your app.

Comment: Hey Tom, I still like to use the Jboss default logging, I would like the slf4j to stop logging into the jboss console/server.log

Comment: this solution doesn't stop the default logging from working. You always will have the server.log file. What it does is, allow your separate file to contain only the application logging that you choose.